# PHP: generate a number from xyz0000 to xyz9999

Tags: php

I am trying to generate a list of numbers (that I can use in a for/foreach cycle).

Any number should be 10 digits long and have an initial prefix (i.e. 0851)

**0851xxxxxx**
and go from
**0851000000**
to 
**0851999999**

Comment: It'd probably be better if you didn't allow a leading zero if working with numbers, since it would be read as an octal and screw everything up.

Comment: I updated the answer with less memory expensive solution. See how you like it.

Answer (score 7):

```
range('0851000000','0851999999')
```

However this array will take as much as 84MB in memory (as reported by `memory_get_usage(1)`)

Less memory consuming way is to generate these numbers on the fly, while you iterate in your loop.

For example

```
for($a = 851000000; $a <= 851999999; $a++) {
  $number = '0'.(string)$a;
  doSomethingWith($number);
}
```

Comment: You need to add the first 0' with this as PHP will remove it in numbers.

Comment: Can we avoid using arrays? the interpreter returns Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)

Comment: Certainly not because of this array. It's 1000000 entries, 8B each. Even assuming that the actual data structure is 5 times as large, it's still 40MB, far from 128MB of your limit.

Comment: Tested: it seems the array takes some 84MB. I'll update the answer with something less momory consuming.

Answer (score 3):

For a random generation, use the following code. Use [Mchl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946433/php-generate-a-number-from-xyz0000-to-xyz9999/4946462#4946462) if you want the entire list of possibilities.

```
$str = sprintf("0851%06d", rand(0, 999999));
```